# No mapping found for HTTP request with URI dispatcher error

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, servlets

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"     
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>SpringMVCTutorial</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
              org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
            </servlet-class>
     <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
   <!-- <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern> -->
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
        <!-- <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern> -->
  </servlet-mapping>
  <context-param>
   <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>      
   <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>    
   </context-param>     
   <listener>      
       <listener-class>           
           org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener       
           </listener-class>    
     </listener>
     <servlet>
  <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
</web-app>
```

this is the file `dispatcher-servlet.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"  
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"  
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"  
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context   
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd  
    ">

<!--     <mvc:annotation-driven /> 
     <mvc:view-controller path=”/index.htm” view-name=”index”/>       -->
<!-- <context:component-scan base-package="controller"/>  -->

<bean name="/helloworld.htm" class="controller.HelloWorldController"/>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter"/> 
<bean name="indexController" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"/>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
    <property name="order" value="0"/>
</bean>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>   
    <bean id="viewResolver"  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="urlMapping"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="mappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="index.htm">indexController</prop>
                <!-- <prop key="helloworld.htm">helloworld</prop> -->
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>   
</beans>
```

and this is my controller

```
package controller;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
@Controller
public class HelloWorldController {
     protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());
     @RequestMapping(value="/helloworld", method = RequestMethod.GET)
      public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
        logger.info("Return View");
        return new ModelAndView("helloworld");
      }
}
```

Can anyone help me to find the reason of this error i already tried multiple solutions as they have the same error but none worked for me its the first time i do Spring from scratch :(..

```
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringMVCTutorial/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'.......
```

Followed by error 404 on the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have two problems here:

First, you need to use `<mvc:annotation-driven />` to enable annotation based controller.

Second, it seems to me that you want to have a default page when typing the context root only.
In this case, you need to add mapping like this:

```
<mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="index.htm"/>
```

Or change `<prop key="index.htm">indexController</prop>` to

`<prop key="/">indexController</prop>`